# Meteor,data context in iron-router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a small problem with the data-context in iron-router

Here is my code

My Collection and routing

```
Prev_Coll=new Meteor.Collection('previous');

Router.map(function(){
    this.route('previousPage',
        {path:'/previousPage/:_id',
        data:  function(){
                return Prev_Coll.findOne({_id:this.params._id});
    }
        });
});
```

My insert command

```
var ee=Prev_Coll.insert({J_one:one,J_two:two});
alert(ee);
Router.go('previousPage', {_id: ee});
```

**My previouspage**

```
<template name="previousPage">

    <p> {{_id}}
        {{J_one}}
        {{J_two}}</p>

</template>
```

Here nothing is displayed in my page.My question is how to read data from data context.

Am i doing in the correct way?

Can anyone pointed me to the answer.Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try placing your `Router.go('previousPage', {_id: ee});` inside a callback from the insert method. E.g. `Prev_Coll.insert({J_one:one,J_two:two}, function (err,id) { Router.go('previousPage', {_id: id}); });`

Comment: Thx for support and still not working.Am i using correct keywords in **PreviousPage** or should i use like `this._id`,`'this.J_one`

Comment: Maybe you should add some logging to see what's going on. Like: `console.log(Prev_Coll.findOne({_id:this.params._id}););console.log(this.params._id);` in your data method in your route to see whether it actually found the record. You can access your console in Chrome with CMD+OPTION+C if you're on a Mac.

Comment: @alste Yeah solved the problem many thx